# Use tabbarViewController.selectedViewContreller didn't push next View

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to use:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

but this didn't work in Swift. But it works if I use:

```
[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController pushViewController:nextVC animated:NO]
```

in Objective-C. Why?

Comment: Why isn't your Swift code the same as your Objective-C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your objective c example the `tabBarController.selectedViewController` is assumed to be the `UINavigationController` instance which is probable correct based on your viewController hierarchy.

However your swift example assumes `tabBarController.selectedViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController` instance which doesn't match with the objective c version. Accessing the navigationController will return nil because you are asking the navigation controller for its parent navigationController (which doesn't exist).

Your swift example can be fixed like so

```
guard let navigationController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController else {
  return
}

navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
tabBarController?.selectedView?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: false)
```